# How to print all pairs of an ArrayList with no duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist

Just a simple question. I know to print all possible pairs, you do a nested for loop with a few more adjustments to be fancier. In my case, I want to take it a step up where pairs are not allowed to repeat or have 2 of the same integer in a pair.

For example: `(0,0) is not allowed, but (0,1) is allowed. If (0,1) is a pair, then (1,0) is not allowed.`

If I had integers "0,1,2,3", then my output would be

```
(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(1,2)(1,3)(2,3)
```

This is my current code that won't print pairs with 2 same integers, but repeated pairs still print.

```
        for(int a = 0; a < 4;a++) {
        numbers.add(a);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(i != j) {
            System.out.println("("+i+" , "+j+")");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `numbers.add(a);` - not being used is it!  What do you think some logic could be?  A big part of being a programmer is to figure out the logic.

Comment: Does this help? [Print all possible combinations of r elements in a given array of size n](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j < 4; j++) {
        if(i != j) {
            System.out.println("("+i+" , "+j+")");
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++) {
        System.out.println("("+i+" , "+j+")");
    }
}
```